# paginate_links function not working with latest WordPress update

Tags: php, wordpress

After updating to WordPress 5.5 I noticed that the pagination I had created on the site did not work anymore. I even tested on a couple other themes and even the latest twenty twenty theme and none are resulting in a page change. Double checked that updating to WordPress 5.5 was the case on another install too and the same problem happens.

Did something change in the latest version that would be effecting this function from working properly?

```
$pagination_counts = paginate_links(
        array(
            'base'      => add_query_arg( 'page', '%#%' ),
            'format'    => '?page=%#%',
            'current'   => max( 1, get_query_var( 'page' ) ),
            'mid_size'  => 3,
            'end_size'  => 3,
            'prev_text' => __( '&#10094;' ),
            'next_text' => __( '&#10095;' ),
            'total'     => ceil( esc_html( $total_pagination_count ) / esc_html( $per_page ) ), // 3 items per page
        )
    );
```

Comment: Can you explain "did not work anymore". When you turn on full error debugging, are you getting an error message? Or is there just whitespace? Also, there's no need to escape your variables here using `esc_html( $total_pagination_count )` that will be handled elsewhere.

Comment: After looking into wordpress core trac on slack I see someone reported a bug on it after 5.5 update. And thanks on the esc_html tip too. https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/50976#comment:7

Comment: Good find @SlickRemix!